# log4j not able to collect logs for child Talend jobs with FileAppender

Tags: log4j, talend

I am using Talend DI 7.1 & its involing log4j 1.2.

My Talend jobs has Master/Parent job: M_1  & two child job: C_11 & C_12 (called from M_1 using tRunJob).

In the configuration of log4j & using DailyRollingFileAppender :

- If file name param is hardcode, say, "/tmp/talend_log4j_logs.log".

  - This file is getting created & rolled over properly.
  - Logs for all M_1, C_11, C_12 is captured properly.

Issue arises when path of Filename is parameterized in job executable project properties. i.e.:
M_1_run.sh has a parameter , say LOG_FILE="/tmp/talend_log4j_logs.log" , and this is used like
**java -D**LOG_FILE=$LOG_FILE.

- Now when this $LOG_FILE is used in DailyRollingFileAppender "file" param value.
- This parameter works fine for Parent job M_1 , but fails to collect any information about C_11 & C_12.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In shell setting of Talend studio under edit/project ,you can use below :

export _java_options="-DLogFileName=$LOGDIR/${talend.job.name}.log"

This will do the system property setting to set the logfilepath